# How to read Host Certificate from Docker Container

Tags: c#, windows, docker, dockerfile, x509

I have a `X509 Certificate` installed in the host environment Windows Store Access.
I try to read that certificate from a running Windows Docker Container.
Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you try to use volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have 2 solutions:

- Use a volume: you can mount the certificat where you want in the container [here you have the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)
- You can use secrets [the documantation is here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret_create/)

As a best-practice it's recomand to use secrets in your case (at least it seems like it since there are not a lot of details in your question).

I hope that answer your question :)